# How to check if list 2 contains all of list 1s elements?

Tags: prolog

I'm quite new to Prolog. I got stuck with this problem:
If I have two lists, how do I check if list 1 contains all of the elements of the second list, but they don't have to be equal. So list 2 might contain more elements.

I know I can use `member/2` to check if a certain element is in a list. But I don't know how to not include these members of both lists after I checked them. So for example:
If I have list `A = [a,b,c,a]` and list `B = [a,b,c,d,e]` and I start by checking if the first 'a' from list A is in list B. Obviously this returns a True, but if I check the last 'a' from list A, I should get a False returned, since list A has 2 'a's and B only 1, instead I get True returned. I really have no clue on how to fix this problem.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me :)
Thanks!

Edit: Explained my question a bit more

Comment: Look at [`member/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=member/2) and look up (Google) ["Prolog basic list processing"](https://www.doc.gold.ac.uk/~mas02gw/prolog_tutorial/prologpages/lists.html). Please show what you've attempted in terms of code and ask a more specific question about where you're stuck.

Comment: I changed my question :)

Comment: Try first yourself, and then ask specific questions (i.e. why doesn't my code do what I am expecting) by providing a minimal, complete, and verifiable example of the code you have already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`select/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=select/3) does exactly what we want:

```
is_sublist([], []).
is_sublist([], [_|_]).
is_sublist([H|T], L) :-
    once(select(H, L, L2)),
    is_sublist(T, L2).
```

We wrap it in [`once/1`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=once/1) to avoid redundant successes in cases where an element appears multiple times.

**Note:** you can remove `once/1` to get more working behaviors:

```
?- is_sublist(Z,[a,b,c]).          % Without once
Z = [] ;
Z = [a] ;
Z = [a, b] ;
Z = [a, b, c] ;
Z = [a, c] ;
Z = [a, c, b] ;
Z = [b] ;
Z = [b, a] ;
Z = [b, a, c] ;
Z = [b, c] ;
Z = [b, c, a] ;
Z = [c] ;
Z = [c, a] ;
Z = [c, a, b] ;
Z = [c, b] ;
Z = [c, b, a] ;
false.
```

This will not enumerate all possible answers in the opposite direction, so not everything is perfect:

```
?- is_sublist([a,b],Z).             % Without once
Z = [a, b] ;
Z = [a, b, _886|_888] ;
Z = [a, _880, b|_888] ;
Z = [a, _880, _892, b|_900] ;
Z = [a, _880, _892, _904, b|_912]
…
```